# Why is there a need for Parse() when TryParse() already exists?

Tags: c#, .net, built-in

`Parse()` method is available in built-in value types, which throws an exception when an incompatible type is found. An unhandled exception is not a good thing. Hence C# also provided the method named `TryParse()` in built-in value types, which handles errors, if any, and returns a boolean response.

So, `TryParse()` is better than `Parse()`. So why is there a need for `Parse()` in C#? When is it needed?
What are the scenarios when we should choose `Parse()` instead of `TryParse()`?

Comment: If you're certain that the value can be parsed to the target type, then why would you prefer `if (TryParse(value out T result)) { DoSomething(); }` over `T result = Parse(value);`? Not to mention that inline `out` variables didn't exist prior to C# 7.0. So, you'd need an extra line for declaring `result`. One more thing, using `Parse()` vs `TryParse()` communicates the _intent_. It's similar to using `First()` vs `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450057/7201774

Comment: There are presumably good example for using Parse that's not my point. My point is look at the history what came first. Mostly when you ask why is there x when y exists its because  x existed earlier and you break valid code in removing functionality.

Comment: "Unhandled exception is not good thing" - that's a bold assertion. If your application cannot continue with invalid data, then letting `Parse` throw an exception is the simplest way of proceeding in my view.

Comment: I note that originally .NET Framework 1.1 only had `Parse` methods - the `TryParse` methods weren't added until .NET Framework 2.0 in 2005 (not to be confused with .NET Core 2.0 in 2017), which meant that a lot of early code had a lot of `try/catch` everywhere, _ew_.

Comment: It's much worse to have a parse fail, and then just _ignoring_ the return value, and assuming it worked.  Depending on the language, that can mean uninitialized data, which can lead to "interesting" bugs.  I can't remember if C# guarantees zero-init of primitives or not, which *helps* but isn't a panacea either.  I know too many programmers that just don't check boolean success/fail.  They can't ignore an exception though.

Comment: _"I can't remember if C# guarantees zero-init of primitives or not"_ - fields are always zeroed. Locals are not, but you will get a compile-time error if you read from a non-initialized or not-always-assigned local.

Comment: I think we can all agree that no-one should be using `Convert.ToInt32` anymore though :)

Comment: @Dai I think you mean `Convert.ToInt32(string)`, specifically. It certainly has some other useful overloads :)

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine The other overloads are redundant: the cast operator is more succinct.

Comment: @Dai Consider `ToInt32(bool)`, `ToInt32(object, IFormatProvider)`, `ToInt32(string value, int fromBase)`. There are some that are useful. Not everything can be done with a simple cast.

Answer (score 1):

> So TryParse() is better than Parse()

Not always. Sometimes you *know* that the value can be parsed to the target type. In which case, would you rather write:

```
T result = T.Parse(value);
```

Or:

```
T result;
if (T.TryParse(value, out result)
{
    /* Do something */
}
```

Which one do you think is better?

> What are the scenarios when we should choose Parse() instead of TryParse?

Here's a real-life example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "^([0-9]{1,3})-", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (var match in matches)
    int number = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Here, the mere fact we have a regex match is enough for us to know that group 1 holds an integer. So, why would we have to write something like this instead?

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out number)
    {

    }
}
```

Theoretically, we could just write:

```
int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out int number)
```

...and then use `number` right away but

- Using a method called `TryXXXX` and not checking the returned `bool` is pretty awkward.
- Inline `out` variables were not a thing before C# 7.0.

Also, using `Parse()` vs `TryParse()` communicates the *intent*. If I use `Parse()`, it indicates to the next person reading my code (which could be future me) that this should never fail and if it does, then something went horribly wrong. This is similar to using `IEnumerable.First()` vs `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault()`. The former communicates that the sequence/collection should *never* be empty.

Comment: _"The former communicates that the sequence/collection should never be empty."_ - the situation would be improved if .NET added something like `INonEmptyCollection<T>`  or if C# supported predicate-types without needing faff around with custom `struct` types.

Comment: @Dai Well, regardless. You could have a collection that _can_ be empty and _needs_ to be empty sometimes, but will never be empty _at a specific point_. In which case, I'd use `First` over `FirstOrDefault`.